# Using a Button from ArrayAdapter to an ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, view, layout-inflater

**I was trying to use a button in a different View i got NullPointerException but now, i tried it this way and i got rid of the NPE but I still cannot make the button to work**

```
layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_for_final, null, true);
        Button mView = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.whyyounowork);
        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Here is my ArrayAdapter

```
class ListForFinale extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] imageId;
    private String[] web;

    public ListForFinale(Activity context,
                         String[] web, String[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_for_final, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        Button button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.whyyounowork);
        TextView imageView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
//        Double d = imageId[position];
//        String s= d.toString();
        imageView.setText(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the text fields and button from a row of a table layout and add it to the listview. the textfields work perfectly but the button's onClickListener is used to delete a particular row from the listview so the only way i can do it is by using the button in the Activity class. but then, the button doesn't perform any actions when clicked in the listview.

My java source files are [on GitHub for more details](https://github.com/JavaIsMyCupOfCoffee/mustached-octo-dubstep)

Comment: You don't set any OnClickListener in your `getView()` method.

Comment: What class and method contains the first code snippet?

Comment: I need to use the onclicklistener of button in my activity so I defined it there.

Comment: Then you should create a named class rather than using an anonymous one.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the myActivity2.java contains the first code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you seem to be using the same layout file in two places, this does *not* mean that you are reusing the same `View` instances. In particular, the `button` variable in your first snippet is a different object than the `button` variable in your `getView()` method. You set the `OnClickListener` for the former, but not for the later.

**Update:**

I have an app that uses a ListView in a somewhat similar way. I apologize in advance for the self-promotion, but it is the best example at hand.

My app is a baseball card inventory system and displays the baseball cards in a ListView. One feature is that the user can select cards from the list to delete them. (My exact mechanism for deleting cards is quite different from what you are trying to do, but I think some of my design decisions will serve as good examples for you.)

To start, I have a [BaseballCard](https://github.com/BaseballCardTracker/bbct/blob/master/gradle/android/src/main/java/bbct/android/common/data/BaseballCard.java) class which holds the baseball card data. This is a simple bean. Individual BaseballCard objects are created from data retrieved from a database. I strongly suggest that you do something similar. You should have a class that represents single shopping cart items and an ArrayList of objects created from this class. This will allow you to dynamically add and remove items much more easily than using arrays.

Then you set the `OnClickListener` for each button in the `getView()` method. Your listener will remove the data from the database or ArrayList then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to allow the ListView to redraw itself. (For my own adapter, you can look [here](https://github.com/BaseballCardTracker/bbct/blob/master/gradle/android/src/main/java/bbct/android/common/provider/BaseballCardAdapter.java). The exact details differ from what you are trying to do, but feel free to borrow ideas.)

Comment: So  I set an onclicklistener in the getView() and then how do I proceed.

Comment: @user3832498 I'm still unclear on what you are attempting to do. Do you want to delete the row from your list view? If so, remove the data from your model and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Comment: that activity is basically a shopping cart.. So the items they don't want to have will be deleted by clicking the button. The button is what I'm trying to get working.

Comment: @user3832498 How do you represent a single item in the shopping cart?

Comment: I have a table layout and have a row with 2 text views and one button at the far right. I use a array list then convert it to a string array then use the constructor of the listforfinale to add the arrays to its respective positions in the listView. I tried notifyDataSetChange() but what's the point any thing inside this button's onclicklistener is pointless since it doesn't even execute it.

Comment: @user3832498 Why do you have a table layout **and** a listview? Are they displaying the same data? Also, note that both of these are the **view** from the Model-View-Controller pattern. You need a separate **model** that stores the actual data.